# Resque + killed worker: does not leave a failed job

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, resque

I noticed that when i kill a resque worker and it's processing something, it won't leave a failed job. It will be simply gone.

Thus, the job will never be finished and jobs place an important role in my application.

This only happens when i kill a worker. If my job raises an exception, i can retry it later.

Is it possible to avoid this behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: Understanding something did you killed the `worker` or the `job` and more important how did you killed it `kill -9`